# Haskell: Left-biased/short-circuiting function

Tags: parsing, haskell

Two classes ago, our professor presented to us a Parser module.

Here is the code:

```
module Parser (Parser,parser,runParser,satisfy,char,string,many,many1,(+++)) where

import Data.Char
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State

type Parser = StateT String []

runParser :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
runParser = runStateT

parser :: (String -> [(a,String)]) -> Parser a
parser = StateT

satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy f = parser $ \s -> case s of
    [] -> []
    a:as -> [(a,as) | f a]

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char = satisfy . (==)

alpha,digit :: Parser Char
alpha = satisfy isAlpha
digit = satisfy isDigit

string :: String -> Parser String
string = mapM char

infixr 5 +++
(+++) :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
(+++) = mplus

many, many1 :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
many p = return [] +++ many1 p
many1 p = liftM2 (:) p (many p)
```

Today he gave us an assignment to introduce "a left-biased, or short-circuiting version of (+++)", called (<++). His hint was for us to consider the original implementation of (+++). When he first introduced +++ to us, this was the code he wrote, which I am going to call the original implementation:

```
infixr 5 +++
(+++) :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
p +++ q = Parser $ \s -> runParser p s ++ runParser q s
```

I have been having tons of trouble since we were introduced to parsing and so it continues.

I have tried/am considering two approaches.

1) Use the "original" implementation, as in p +++ q = Parser $ \s -> runParser p s ++ runParser q s

2) Use the final implementation, as in (+++) = mplus

Here are my questions:

1) The module will not compile if I use the original implementation. The error: Not in scope: data constructor 'Parser'. It compiles fine using (+++) = mplus. What is wrong with using the original implementation that is avoided by using the final implementation?

2) How do I check if the first Parser returns anything? Is something like (not (isNothing (Parser $ \s -> runParser p s) on the right track? It seems like it should be easy but I have no idea.

3) Once I figure out how to check if the first Parser returns anything, if I am to base my code on the final implementation, would it be as easy as this?:

```
-- if p returns something then
p <++ q = mplus (Parser $ \s -> runParser p s) mzero
-- else
(<++) = mplus
```

Best,
Jeff

P.S.
Oh yeah, and what the heck does this code do?? Even when it compiles, I have no idea how to test it to ensure that it is working as intended.

Comment: As to 1), change "Parser" to "parser" in the body of `(+++)`. You don't have Parser as constructor since it's just a type synonym.

Comment: Note - it looks like you lectures are derived from Graham Hutton's book "Programming in Haskell". Graham avoids Haskell's `newtype` syntax to make the book easier to follow but it does mean the code in the book won't compile as is (there's a note at the end of the chapter regarding this). Possibly you missed receiving some code your professor gave out in the lectures: the original Parser module is Hutton's original, simplified code; but the later (+++) is implemented in legal Haskell as you would use with newtypes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot going on here! What you're looking at is a (non-deterministic) "parser combinator library" and you can find other examples in `parsec`, `attoparsec`, `uu-parsinglib`... it's quite a common idea in Haskell, but it's certainly a little complex. I'll unpack the core idea a bit here.

---

The first idea to consider is the concept of an incremental parsing "step". This is the thing represented in the above code by `Parser a` which you might think of as "run a parsing step which attempts to parse something of type `a`".

A "parsing step" involves taking a look at some kind of input stream of characters, pulling off however many are needed to represent some `a` type, then returning both that fresh `a` and the leftover characters that weren't used. At this level of description it's easy to write that out in Haskell

```
String {- input stream -} -> (a {- fresh -}, String {- leftovers -})
```

This is the basis of a parser step and it's worth noting it's such a common idiom that outside of parsing libraries we call it `State String a`.

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }

>>> :t runState (undefined :: State String a)
String -> (a, String)
```

We could try constructing a parser step as well in this exploded format. Consider a parser which consumes a single character to create an `Int`

```
parseInt :: String -> (Int, String)
parseInt (x:xs) = case x of
  '0' -> (0, xs)
  '1' -> (1, xs)
  ...
  '9' -> (9, xs)
  _   -> error "What! Failure!"
parseInt []     = error "What! Another failure!"

>>> parseInt "3leftovers"
(3, "leftovers")
```

Immediately we can see that this model is too simple---we can only provide parser failure by throwing errors all the way up to the runtime. That's dangerous and suggests that we're poorly modeling our parser. We can add failure to it pretty trivially, though.

```
-- String -> Maybe (a, String)

parseInt :: String -> Maybe (Int, String)
parseInt []     = Nothing
parseInt (x:xs) = case x of
  '0' -> Just (0, xs)
  '1' -> Just (1, xs)
  ...
  '9' -> Just (9, xs)
  _   -> Nothing

>>> parseInt "foo"
Nothing
```

This too is a very common Haskell theme even outside of parsers called a State Transformer or `StateT`. The definition looks like this

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a, s) }

>>> :t runStateT (undefined :: StateT String Maybe a)
String -> Maybe (a, String)
```

It's allowing us to combine the notions of failure that `Maybe` embodies with the notions of `State` from the original parser. Indeed, that's what your professor did with his own version, except instead of using `Maybe` he used `[]`

```
>>> :t runStateT (undefined :: StateT String [] a)
String -> [(a, String)]
```

which allows for both failure (as the empty list `[]`) and *multiple* simultaneous successes. This is what makes his parser non-deterministic---it collects and handles multiple successes with each parsing step. This can be very bad for memory, but is a powerful technique used carefully.

---

There's something else missing in what I've written about so far, though---how can we combine multiple parsers together? It's fairly painful to run `parseInt` three times, for instance

```
parse3Ints :: String -> Maybe ((Int, Int, Int), String)
parse3Ints input = case parseInt input of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just (i1, input') -> case parseInt input' of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just (i2, input'') -> case parseInt input'' of
      Nothing -> Nothing
      Just (i3, leftovers) -> Just ((i1, i2, i3), leftovers)
```

Ugh. Can we do better? We need to somehow thread together both the failures and the passing of the `input` string. Fortunately, this is exactly what `Monad`s do and all three of the data types we've seen so are already `Monad`s with these exact behaviors

```
instance Monad m => Monad (StateT s m) where ...
instance Monad [] where ...
instance Monad Maybe where ...
```

Note that `StateT` is a `Monad` only if its `m` parameter is---this is because it allows us to layer `Monad`s together and thus it needs to invoke the "inner" `Monad` in order to do its own sequencing.

The upshot is that by converting these simple functions into `StateT String Maybe a` or `StateT String [] a` we immediately get to use `do`-notation to have the built-in `Monad` instances handle our complex sequencing

```
parse3Ints :: StateT String Maybe (Int, Int, Int)
parse3Ints = do
  i1 <- parseInt
  i2 <- parseInt
  i3 <- parseInt
  return (i1, i2, i3)

-- or even
parse3Ints = liftM3 (,,) parseInt parseInt parseInt
```

---

The final point of interest here gets to your professors question about `(+++)`. Here he's using the `mplus` function which comes from the `MonadPlus` typeclass of which `StateT` and `[]` are instances. We can take a peek at that code

```
instance MonadPlus [] where
  mzero = []
  mplus as bs = as ++ bs

instance MonadPlus m => MonadPlus (StateT s m) where
  mzero                         = StateT $ \input -> mzero
  mplus (StateT sa) (StateT sb) = StateT $ \input -> mplus (sa input) (sb input)
```

So we can see that the real weight of this code is on the `[]` instance as the `StateT` instance just passes the buck to its inner `Monad`, `m`.

What is `MonadPlus []` doing? It's indicating the notion of combining failures using "or". If `[]` is failure in the list `Monad` then `mzero` is immediate failure and `mplus as bs` is failure only if *both* `as` and `bs` are. We can write that as

```
mplus mzero a = a
mplus a mzero = a
```

Which is the kind of algebraic law that people might think of as definitional for `MonadPlus` (though there is some controversy here, it's immaterial to the code here).

---

So by using the `mplus` instance to combine parsers, what's going on? In short, it allows you to "or" parsers together such that they only fail if all of the parsers together fail.

```
(pa +++ pb +++ pc) is mzero ONLY if pa, pb, AND pc are mzero
```

This works nicely in the list `Monad` because it allows us to collect multiple successes together. There is no bias because the list monad tries all of the various parses together, they all just go in the list without any priority.

We can compare this with the `Maybe` `Monad` which is inherently biased as it only gets to consider "the best" parse success at any given time. To wit, we can look at the `MonadPlus` instance for `Maybe`

```
instance MonadPlus Maybe where
  mzero                   = Nothing
  mplus Nothing x         = x
  mplus x Nothing         = x
  mplus (Just a) (Just b) = Just a
```

In the last line of the `mplus` definition we throw away all but the "leftmost" success. This is the heart of left-biasing.

But as I stated a long time ago, it might be a bad thing for us to prioritize all the parses equally. It can be very painful in memory to store the entire tree of potential parses and carry it along as each new character is consumed.

To this end, we can left bias `(+++)` as `(<++)`. The idea here is that we want to return successful parses immediately and only pass it on "rightward" if we must

```
StateT sa <++ StateT sb = StateT $ \input -> case sa input of
  []   -> sb input
  els  -> els
```

Here we *only* try the `sb` parser if the `sa` parser produces no results. This means we throw away a lot of potential "right" parses to speed along the way on our "left" parses. It lets us prune the tree of potential parses judiciously.

Comment: `else` is reserved keyword, you cannot use it as a variable name

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed and helpful comment! Based on your example code, I ended up with this: `p <++ q = parser $ \s -> case p s of [] -> runParser q s _ -> runParser p s ` But I get an error: "Couldn't match expected type 'String -> [t0]' with actual type 'StateT String [] a'. I am confused about this. p is supposed to be of type Parser a. s is supposed to be of type String. runParser p s thus fulfills its type signature and should return a type [(a,String)]. Would parser $ \s -> runParser p s do parser (runParser p s)? I'm getting befuddled at this point.

Comment: Good catch! I'll fix it.

Comment: My other attempt: 'p <++ q = parser $ \s -> case p s of [] -> q s els -> els' returns error: Couldn't match expected type 'String -> [(a, String)]' with actual type 'StateT String [] a' Unfortunately I need to run now but I will revisit the topic later tonight. Thanks so much for your help !

Comment: There's some debugging that'll be required, but hopefully I've covered most of the intuition and mechanics in my post. Think carefully about how `Parser` is made up from `StateT`.

Comment: I think I got it :) `infixr 5 <++
(<++) :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
p <++ q = parser $ \input -> case runParser p input of
    [] -> runParser q input
    els -> els` Once again, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

- 1) As @andras pointed out, change `Parser` to `parser`
- 2+3) Look at the code for `+++`

`p +++ q = parser $ \s -> runParser p s ++ runParser q s`

We can expand it a bit, to make things clearer

```
p +++ q = parser $ \s -> resP ++ resQ
  where resP = runParser p s
        resQ = runParser q s
```

This requires just a small alteration (in `resP +++ resQ`) to make `<++` left biased.